# How do I use two Samsung 28" model lu28e590ds/za monitors with a MacBook pro?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, macbook, usb-c

I was pointed here after I hit a dead end, sorry if this is the wrong place for this question, I'll gladly repost elsewhere.

The issue I'm having is as follows:

I have two of [these monitors](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/uhd-and-wqhd/samsung-uhd-28-monitor-with-high-glossy-black-finish-lu28e590ds-za/), I'll call one monitor A and the other B because somehow they actually behave differently. On both a 2018 15in Macbook Pro and a 2019 16inch Macbook. I've used monitor A for longer and it works fine, connected through HDMI to a USB-C dock I have. Now I got monitor B which I'd like to use for a 3 screen setup, connecting it through HDMI and a dongle to the same computer. When I connect all three, regardless of the order of operations or which monitor is connected by which cable through which dongle/dock on any usb-c port on the computer, I get the same result - all displays detected by the computer but monitor A stops receiving input. If I plug monitor A in first, I get my input and everything's fine. Then I plug in monitor B and monitor A's input disappears.

I am absolutely stumped. I've used three monitors on both Macs before, but never in combination with one of these particular monitors and I can't go to my office to collect another monitor what with the pandemic. I purchased both in never-used condition from a friend.

Would appreciate any trouble shooting tips. Thank you!